# POST request not returning updated data

Tags: javascript, php, post

I'm implementing the comments system on my PHP platform that is based on Laravel 4.

The problem at the moment is that when I send a new comment it gets saved into the database but then the comments list returned doesn't contain the just inserted comment.

So, bottom up, this is the path the comment "follows" before reaching the database:

This function just pass the comment's data to another function, manage some UI elements and then retrieve a list of all the comments if everything is OK:

```
$("#comments-button-new").click(function() {

    var parameters = url.getURLParameters();
    var entryID = parameters.pop(); // Put this inside a data attribute

    comments.sendComment(
        $("#comments-input-comment-new").val(),
        entryID,
        $("#comments-token").val(),
        function() {

            $("#comments-alert-error").addClass('hidden');
            $("#comments-button-new").html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span>");
            getComments(); // When the POST response is received comments are retrieved
        },
        function() {

            $("#comments-alert-error").removeClass('hidden');
        }
    );
});
```

This is the function that actually make the POST request to the server:

```
function sendComment(content, entryID, token, doneCallback, failCallback) {

    $.post("http://localhost/comment/new",
        {
            content : content,
            entryID : entryID,
            _token  : token
        })
        .done(doneCallback())
        .fail(function(xhr) {

            failCallback(xhr.response);
        });
}
```

This is the controller that handles the comment:

```
public function newComment() {

    $content = Input::get('content');
    $entryID = Input::get('entryID');

    $hashids = new \Hashids\Hashids(Config::get('security.salt'), Config::get('security.minimumHashLength'));
    $entryID = $hashids->decrypt($entryID);

    $comment = new Comment();
    $result = $comment->newComment($content, $entryID[0]);

    if($result != 'OK') {

        return Response::make($result, 500);
    }

    return Response::make('OK', 200);
}
```

And this is the `newComment` function located in the `Comment` model that saves the comment in the DB:

```
public function newComment($content, $entryID) {

    $validator = Validator::make(
        array(
            'content' => $content,
            'entryID' => $entryID
        ),
        array(
            'content' => 'max:'.self::$COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH,
            'entryID' => 'exists:entries,id'
        )
    );
    if($validator->fails()) {

        return $validator->messages()->all();
    }

    $this->author        = Auth::user()->username;
    $this->content       = $content;
    $this->parentEntryID = $entryID;
    $this->save(); // Comment is saved in the Database

    return 'OK';
}
```

The comment is correctly saved in the database, then, following the returns you can see that after that I want to retrieve all entry's comments. Problem is that all the comments but one are returned.
If I try to reload the page than every comment, including the last one, is returned.

It looks like that the `getComments` JS function is executed before the comment is saved in the DB.

**Edit**:

Not sure if relevant or not but the JS functions make use of **require.js**.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `.always()` to your `$.post` and calling your `doneCallback()` there? `.always()` is always the last thing to run in the `post()` sequence, so it may make a difference.

Comment: But that would be executed even with POST returning with 500 status.

Comment: True, but there's no reason why you couldn't handle the errors within the function. I was more thinking to test if it is a timing issue or not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `sendComment` function, you've written `.done(doneCallback())`. That is, you're running your `doneCallback` at the time you set up your AJAX post - *not* when you get get a response from the server. And your callback function is undefined, so nothing will happen.

It's a simple fix: replace that line with `.done(doneCallback)`. That way, the `doneCallback` you pass into your `sendComment` function will be invoked when the POST returns successfully, not when it's set up.

Comment: Thank you, i really didn't notice that mistake. You saved me an headache :)